# Linking static library to .cpp file

Tags: c++, compilation, static-libraries, static-linking, .a

I have a libcx3d.a which contains my VrmlParser class and other classes which are used by VrmlParser.

I have a main.cpp which does this :

```
VrmlParser vp = new VrmlParser();  
double **VOB = vp.getVOB();`
```

I compiled using:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -L. -lcx3d
```

I get the  following errors :

```
 'VrmlParser' was not declared in this scope. expected ';' before vp.   
 'vp' was not declared in this scope.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: This is *not* a linking problem, it's a compilation problem. (It looks like you're just missing a header file.) Try compiling your file with `-c` first. Once that succeeds, *then* try and link it.

Comment: There is a header file called "VrmlParser.h" in the static library. Should I include this header file in main.cpp ?

Comment: A "static library" is a compiled binary. The header file does not exist *in* the library. You use the header file *for* that library in *your* code, so it understands the data structures. So yes, include it in your `main.cpp`.

Comment: Sorry for being so noob. But how can I get the header file for that library ?

Comment: Surely everything you need comes from wherever you [download](http://openvrml.org/download) the library from.  Often times in Linux there is a 'libfoo' and a 'libfoo-devel', where the latter includes the header files needed to compile an application using that library.

Comment: I downloaded the source code of the library, added a VrmlParser class to the src folder and a VrmlParser.h to the include folder and built the source codes using the makefiles given to get the .a . I used cygwin to build the library. There is no 'libfoo' or 'libfoo-devel'.